# ajax in wordpress not calling php function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

wonder if anyone can help; I'm trying to implement some ajax through jquery onto a form in a wordpress template.

The jquery is working, and the I can log a console message in the sucess: section, but the data is 0, when it should be calling the php function (at the moment on the same page, and I can call this directly)

so I guess the jquery is working, the admin-ajax is being called, its just the php function is not being called. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong ? I don't fully understand hooks, so perhaps that is an issue - that I need to hook something in somewhere?

jquery (domain would replace comments)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $( "#movies" ).autocomplete({
                minLength:2,
                delay:500,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "http://<!--domain here -->/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            action: 'getMoviesForCode',
                            searchString: $("#movies").val()
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response(data);
                            console.log('jjj'+data);
                        }
                    });
                }           
        });
    });
    </script>
```

php function (on same page)

```
<?php

    function getMoviesForCode(){
echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"hh\");
        </script>
    ";
   $searchString = $_POST['searchString'];
   $results = va_getMoviesForCode($searchString);  
  $results = json_encode($results);
  die($results);
}
 ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You php function should be in your theme's `functions.php` file.

You should then hook the function to `wp_ajax_[your_action]` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_[your_action]`.

Example of what should be in your `functions.php` :

```
function getMoviesForCode(){
echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"hh\");
        </script>
    ";
   $searchString = $_POST['searchString'];
   $results = va_getMoviesForCode($searchString);  
  $results = json_encode($results);
  die($results);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_getMoviesForCode', 'getMoviesForCode');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getMoviesForCode', 'getMoviesForCode');
```

Comment: Hi, That's brilliant -  I can now see the return in firebug response so it's calling the function correctly. just need to get the autocomplete to work in the field now, many thanks !

Comment: by the way i changed it to add_action('wp_ajax_getMoviesForCode', 'getMoviesForCode');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getMoviesForCode', 'getMoviesForCode'); - I'm guessing that's right ?

Comment: thanks for the link, I'll hve a look. it's quite good knowing a bit more about ajax, thinking I'll be using it alot more now !

Comment: Hi, if we write a plugin then can I handle the backend in plugin php file without writin in function.php?

Comment: Yes, the advantage of using a plugin is that you still have the functionality if you change theme.